# Unmanaged dependency not published to hosting app

Tags: c#, wcf, unmanaged

I have a self-hosting WCF service consisting of a console app calling a WCF service library, which are separate projects in the same solution. The service library project depends on an unmanaged dll that is copied to it's output folder using the following  `<Targets>` tag in the `.csproj` file

```
 <Target Name="Pesky64BitAPI" AfterTargets="AfterBuild"> 
    <ItemGroup> 
        <UnmanagedDependencies Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)..\Packages\Pesky64BitAPI*.*\lib\net461\*.*"/> 
    </ItemGroup> 
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(UnmanagedDependencies)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)"></Copy> 
 </Target>
```

This copies the dll over just fine for testing the library. However, the dll needs to be in the build output folder of the console app for deployment. Console app code follows just in case:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {       
        try
        {
            var host = OpenHost();

            Console.ReadKey();

            CloseHost(host);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Omitted for brevity.
        }
    }

    private static void CloseHost(ServiceHost host)
    {
        host.Close();
    }

    private static ServiceHost OpenHost()
    {
        var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(EdnaService));

        // Non-blocking call.
        host.Open();

        return host;
    }
}
```

**Question**: Is there a way to change build targets, or something else, to get the dll added to the app hosting the service library? Or, do I have to duplicate the NuGet package in the console app even though it doesn't directly need it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a post-build event to copy the library? It's not the most elegant solution, but it is simple to do.

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example?

Comment: Also, I would like a generic a solution as possible. For instance, I will probably eventually host in IIS and would like the solution to take into account whatever app hosts the service library. If such a method does not exist, I guess I need to know that too.